# How to make inset effect text shadow over video background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I'm gonna use **inset effect text** shadow over video background but not effected on it. here is my code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

#image-slider {
    position: relative;
}

#image-slider > div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
        margin-top: -200px;
        font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    left: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 6em;
    padding: 120px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.inset-text-effect {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: none;
  font: normal 70px/1 "Aladin", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(48,48,48,1);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: normal;
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  white-space: pre;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(140,140,140,0.6) , -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.67) ;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="http://inserthtml.com/demos/javascript/background-videos/flowers.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://inserthtml.com/demos/javascript/background-videos/flowers.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div class="content">
        Text over Video
    </div>
<div class="inset-text-effect">Inset Text over Video</div>
</div>
```

As you can see inset is not over video background, how to make it?
And please add CSS that texts will be exactly in middle of page, I used **top:50%**  but still it's not in the middle.

Questions:

> 1: How to use **inset text effect** over video background?
>
> 2: How to make text exactly in middle / center of page?

Thanks in advance